# Crystal Reports Viewer Scale Report Page to Fit Printer Page Disabled

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

Need help with determining how to disable Scale Report Page to Fit Printer Page for VB.NET because all my crystal reports print outs are smaller.  I have coded the program to not scale during run-time but nothing seems to make a difference in terms of disabling the Scale Report Page to Fit Printer Page.

```
Dim printPrompt As New Windows.Forms.PrintDialog
printPrompt.PrinterSettings = New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
printPrompt.AllowSomePages = True

Dim oLayout As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings
oLayout.Centered = False
oLayout.Scaling = PrintLayoutSettings.PrintScaling.DoNotScale

Dim margins As PageMargins
margins = rpt.PrintOptions.PageMargins
margins.bottomMargin = 0
margins.leftMargin = 0
margins.rightMargin = 0
margins.topMargin = 0
rpt.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(margins)

rpt.PrintToPrinter(printPrompt.PrinterSettings, printPrompt.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings, False, oLayout)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

did you check Page Setup in editing mode of report?
when you create a report in VS you can config Page Setup.
visual studio menu=>Crystal Reports=>Design=> Page Setup...